# Do I need transit visa for Malaysia

Tags: transit-visas, malaysia, sri-lankan-citizens, airasia

I’m Sri Lankan passport holder. I’m planning to travel from Japan to Sri Lanka via Malaysia by March 2020. Still I have valid Japan student visa until July 2020. Do I need transit visa for Malaysia when I travel with AirAsia.

Comment: Did you book your flights as a single ticket? And if not, are you planning to bring hold luggage?

Answer (score 1):

**Transit Visa:**
The Transit Visa is issued to foreign nationals who require a visa to enter Malaysia on transit to other countries. Foreign nationals on transit without leaving the airport premises and who continue their journey to the next destination with the same flight do not require a transit visa.

**TWoV (Transit without Visa)**
The Transit Without Visa (TWOV) is only applicable after clearing Malaysian Immigration – for a maximum of 120 hours stop-over in Malaysia. However, granting Transit Without Visa (TWOV) is solely at the discretion of the Malaysian Immigration; even if guest(s) meet all the required criteria.

**Countries eligible for Transit Without Visa**

**Indian Subcontinent**

1. Sri Lanka
2. India
3. Pakistan
4. Bangladesh

*Diplomatic & Official Passports only*

**Eligibility**

- Onward ticket must be within 120 hours.
- Must arrive and depart only via the same airport. (E.g. Arrive in KLIA2, Depart from KLIA2)
- Posses a valid onward ticket and carry a Single Entry Visa (SEV) or Multiple Entry Visa (MEV) issued from/and are heading to any one (1) of the seven (7) countries listed below (*TWOV will not be issued if next country of destination is not listed as above):

*Australia,New Zealand,United States of America (USA),Japan,China,Taiwan,South Korea*

Passport MUST have a minimum validity of 6 months.

A PRINTED copy of itinerary and original tickets MUST be produced. Producing only a PNR/booking number will be denied access.

Hold a valid long-term pass* of a 3rd country. 
Note: The definition of a long-term pass of a 3rd country is employment/work permit, expatriate card, student pass or permanent resident card. It is worth noting that a permanent multiple entry visa (MEV) above does not fall under this category and as such, NOT PERMITTED.

**Other Countries**

- Bhutan
- China
- Myanmar
- Nepal
- Vietnam

**Eligibility**

- Onward ticket must be within 120 hours.
- Guest(s) may arrive & depart via AirAsia / other airline and connect/depart via said airlines; as long as flights departing the country depart from the same entry point.
- Must hold confirmed onward ticket to a 3rd / next country.
- Passport MUST have a minimum validity of 6 months.
- A PRINTED copy of itinerary and original tickets MUST be produced. Producing only a PNR / booking number will be denied access.